# MySql 5.6.17 Error #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, constraints, wampserver

I'm tryin to create a table "SIGNATURE" in my database I want this table to have a double primary key and add a foreign key constraint to both primary key that references table "TRAITEMENT"

```
CREATE TABLE TRAITEMENT (
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
dateHeurePrevue DATETIME NOT NULL,
commentaire LONGTEXT,
dateValidation TIMESTAMP,
CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (id,dateHeurePrevue),
CONSTRAINT FK_traitement_consigne FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES consigne(id))     ENGINE=InnoDB;
create unique index id_dateheureprevue on traitement(id, dateheureprevue);

CREATE TABLE SIGNATURE (
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
idPersonne INTEGER NOT NULL,
dateTimeTraitement DATETIME NOT NULL,
retard INTEGER,
motifRetard INTEGER,
heureEffectiveTraitement DATETIME NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (id,dateTimeTraitement),
CONSTRAINT FK_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES traitement(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_idPersonne FOREIGN KEY (idPersonne) REFERENCES personne(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_motifRetard FOREIGN KEY (motifRetard) REFERENCES retard(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_dateTimeTraitement FOREIGN KEY (dateTimeTraitement) REFERENCES traitement(dateHeurePrevue))ENGINE=InnoDB;
create unique index id_dateTimetraitement on signature(id, dateTimeTraitement);
```

Obviously ( I tried to remove it and it worked fine) the problem comes from this forign key :

```
CONSTRAINT FK_dateTimeTraitement FOREIGN KEY (dateTimeTraitement) REFERENCES traitement(dateHeurePrevue)
```

I don't understand, i don't see any conflicts of type,keys...
If anyone can help me solve this problem...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be because your foreign key statement only references part of the main table's primary key?

Comment: check your collation type

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key must be exactly equal to the primary key fields, so:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_dateTimeTraitement FOREIGN KEY (id, dateTimeTraitement) REFERENCES traitement(id, dateHeurePrevue)
```